# Merging JSON objects with common values

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array, json

I am trying to merge JSON objects which have common values.

This is the original JSON:

```
{
    "setA":[
        {
            "setId":"setA"
            ,"prodId":"A"
            ,"price":"5"
            ,"delivertCost":"1"
            ,"name":"Set_Prod01"
        }

        ,{
            "setId":"setA"
            ,"prodId":"B"
            ,"price":"5"
            ,"delivertCost":"1"
            ,"name":"Set_Prod01"
        }
    ]
}
```

Since it has same `setId` and `name`, I want to make it like this:

```
{
    "setA": {
        "setId":"setA"
        ,"prodId":"A,B"
        ,"price":"5"
        ,"deliveryCost":3
        ,"name":"Set_Prod01"
    }
}
```

To do this, I made this JavaScript code, but it looks terrible and more elements have attributes with `if else` than needed.

```
function groupBy(coll, f) {
  return coll.reduce(function(acc, x) {
    var k = f(x);
    acc[k] = (acc[k] || []).concat(x);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

var test = {
  items: [{
    setId: 'setA', prodId: "A", price: '5', deliveryCost : '1', name: "Set_Prod01"
  }, {
    setId: 'setA', prodId: "B", price :'5', deliveryCost : '2', name: "Set_Prod01"
  }]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(test));

var result = groupBy(test.items, function(x){return x.setId});
//first grouping
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

//begin spagetti code... T^T
var secondResult = {};
for(var key in result){
    var secondObjForSet = {};
    var setGroup = result[key]; 
    for(var i = 0; i < setGroup.length; i++) {
        var singleSetItem = setGroup[i];
        for(var innerKey in singleSetItem){
            if(innerKey == 'deliveryCost'){
                secondObjForSet[innerKey] = (typeof secondObjForSet[innerKey] === 'undefined') ? 0 + singleSetItem[innerKey] : (secondObjForSet[innerKey] * 1) + (singleSetItem[innerKey] * 1);
            }else if(innerKey == 'prodId'){
                secondObjForSet[innerKey] = 
                    (typeof secondObjForSet[innerKey] === 'undefined' || secondObjForSet[innerKey] == '') ? 
                        singleSetItem[innerKey] : secondObjForSet[innerKey] + ',' + singleSetItem[innerKey];
            }
            else{
                secondObjForSet[innerKey] = singleSetItem[innerKey];
            }
        }
    }
    secondResult[key] = secondObjForSet;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(secondResult));
```

This is not flexible at all, so I need some help to make it more efficient.

Comment: Why is `deliveryCost` 3 and not 2 (1 + 1)? How about `price`? Why isn't a sum? Not sure I understand what you need...

Comment: Can you explain which fields are merged, which fields are added, which fields remain the same, what's the criteria for merge rather than just throw us some input, output and code?

Comment: @elclanrs server send me summed up product price, but they send delivery cost separately.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer `delivery cost` must summed up. and `prodId` have to connected with comma, and remain others. The code I provided is working, but I think it is totally not efficient.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after answers have arrived, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have the correct target to transform (the input array is filtered).

If you are using es6:

```
const input = [
    {
        "setId": "setA",
        "prodId": "A",
        "price": 5,
        "deliveryCost": 1,
        "name": "Set_Prod01"
    },
    {
        "setId": "setA",
        "prodId": "B",
        "price": 5,
        "deliveryCost": 2,
        "name": "Set_Prod01"
    }
];

const output = {
    "setId": "setA",
    "prodId": "A,B",
    "price": 5,
    "deliveryCost": 3,
    "name": "Set_Prod01"
};

const groupBy = (input) => (
    Object.assign(
        input[0],
        {
            prodId: input.map(set => set.prodId).join(','),
            deliveryCost: input.map(set => set.deliveryCost).reduce( (cur, next) => cur + next)
        }
    )
);

console.log(output);
console.log(groupBy(input));
```

If you are using es6 and stage-2 object spread operator, change the function to:

```
const groupBy = (input) => (
    {
        ...input[0],
        prodId: input.map(set => set.prodId).join(','),
        delivertCost: input.map(set => set.deliveryCost).reduce( (cur, next) => cur + next)
    }
);
```

If you are not using es6, simplest method is use it, and use babel to convert it into es5 compatible code. It's less code, more readable and easier to maintain.

**EDIT**:
The function above simply take an array of objects and assign them into another object. Note that in `Object.assign`, the latter's value will overwrite the former's value with the same key, so you can easily implement the overwriting rule you mentioned. The value are simply some functional programming, one join the array of string, and the other sum up the values.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that the author can learn from your thought process.

Comment: Oops i'm sorry, I updated the reason in the answer above.

Comment: I think it is quite a late, but thanks for your well-formed answer!